# Python Selenium More Efficient Way of Adding Several Users

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am creating a few test cases that will populate a fresh web app account. In this case I would like to add several users at once. This is what I am using now:

```
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.ss-med.small").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.ss-med.small").send_keys("tester1")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input[@value=''])[2]").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input[@value=''])[2]").send_keys("password")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.btn.btn-primary").click()

    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.ss-med.small").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.ss-med.small").send_keys("tester2")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input[@value=''])[2]").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input[@value=''])[2]").send_keys("password")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.btn.btn-primary").click()

    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.ss-med.small").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.ss-med.small").send_keys("tester3")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input[@value=''])[2]").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input[@value=''])[2]").send_keys("password")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.btn.btn-primary").click()
```

... and continuing this pattern until I have reached the number of users I desire.
I know that python has some while loops that I could use, I just don't know how to implement them in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# if you want 100 users...
for n in range(100):
    # you should consider moving these to a separate object that represents the page
    # AKA Page Object Design
    username_field = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.ss-med.small")
    password_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input[@value=''])[2]")
    submit_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.btn.btn-primary")

    username_field.clear()
    username_field.send_keys('tester{}'.format(n))
    password_field.clear()
    password_field.send_keys('password')
    submit_button.click()
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge on this subject. Your solution is working just as I wanted.